# $\mathrm{E}\left(\int_0^ts\mathrm{d}(B_s^2)\right)^2$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, random

Here is a practice problem I encountered with Stochastic integral expectation. **How to use Ito's formula to calculate the expectation of the following stochastic integral?**
$$
\mathrm{E}\left(\int_0^ts\mathrm{d}(B_s^2)\right)^2
$$
$B_t$ is standard Brownian motion.

I have tried to calculate the expectation by the following way:
$$f(xy)=xy=tB_t^2$$
use **Ito formula**
$$
tB_t^2 =\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2ds+\int_{0}^{t}sdB_s^2+\frac12\int_{0}^{t}1d\langle B^2,t\rangle +\frac12\int_{0}^{t}1d\langle B^2,t\rangle +\frac12\int_{0}^{t}0d\langle s\rangle+\frac12\int_{0}^{t}0d\langle B\rangle_s
$$
But I am not sure
$$ \langle B^2,t\rangle=0 $$
If $$ \langle B^2,t\rangle=0 $$ is incorrect, is there another way to calculate this expectation?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Here's a generous hint: Consider the last integral. The integral $\int_0^t s dB_s$ is an example of a Wiener integral--integrating a function of time $t$ alone against the stochastic Brownian integrand. It is a well-known fact (check your notes/textbook!) that $\int_0^t f(s) dB_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0, v(t)^2)$ where $v(t)^2 = \int_0^t f(s)^2 ds$ is the variance (keyword: Ito isometry!). Lastly, think about what is $\mathbb{E}(e^X)$ for an arbitrary normal $X$ (keyword: moment-generating function!). So this last example does not require Ito's formula at all.

Comment: To clarify, you do not want a solution using Itos formula, or you do not know how to apply Itos formula to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Since some people use the horrible notation $(dB_t)^2=dt$ instead of $d\langle B\rangle_t=dt$ please confirm that it is not what you want in, say,
$$\tag{1}
\int_0^ts\,dB_s^2\,.
$$
It seems you want
$$\tag{2}
\int_0^ts\,d(B_s)^2\,.
$$
If that is the case, here is my hint: By Ito,
$$\tag{3}
d(B_s)^2=2\,B_s\,dB_s+\,ds\,.
$$
This leaves you with the very easy task to "calculate" the expectation of
the right hand side in
$$\tag{4}
\int_0^ts\,d(B_s)^2=2\int_0^ts\,B_s\,dB_s+\frac{t^2}{2}\,.
$$
Alternatively you can start with
\begin{align}\tag{5}
\int_0^ts\,d(B_s)^2&=tB_t^2-\int_0^tB_s^2\,ds\,.
\end{align}
The expectation of this is
\begin{align}\tag{6}
\mathbb E\Big[\int_0^ts\,d(B_s)^2\Big]=t\mathbb E[B_t^2]-\int_0^t\mathbb E[B_s^2]\,ds=t^2-\int_0^ts\,ds=\frac{t^2}{2}
\end{align}
as it should.

Using (4) you could have a very easy life calculating
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\Big[\Big(\int_0^ts\,d(B_s)^2\Big)^2\Big]&=
\mathbb E\Big[\Big(2\int_0^ts\,B_s\,dB_s\Big)^2\Big]+\frac{t^4}{4}\tag{7}\\
&\stackrel{\text{Ito isometry}}{=}4\,\mathbb E\Big[\int_0^ts^2\,B_s^2\,ds\Big]+\frac{t^4}{4}\tag{8}\\
&=4\int_0^ts^3\,ds+\frac{t^4}{4}\,.\tag{9}
\end{align}
I let you finish.

Comment: $$\int_0^ts\mathrm{d}B_s^2=tB_t^2-\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2ds$$,$$\mathrm{E}\left(\int_0^ts\mathrm{d}B_s^2\right)^2=\mathrm{E}\left(t^2B_t^4-2tB_t^2\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2ds+(\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2ds)^2\right)$$,but  I don't know how to calculate $$  \mathrm{E}\left(2tB_t^2\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2ds\right),\mathrm{E}\left(\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2ds\right)^2$$

Comment: @user1171881 Use my relation (4) instead of trying it the hard way.